# Jquery: get name of option field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to copy a name of the selected html form option field to another field using jquery.
This is what i got now:

#### script

```
$(document).ready(
function()
{
    //check for change on the categories menu
    $('#categories').change(function() { 

    //get category value
    name = $('#categories').text();
    $('#name').val(name)

});

});
```

#### HTML

```
<form action="editcat.pnp" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<table>
<tr>
<td><label for="category">Category:</label></td><td><select name="category_id"     id="categories">
<option value="1">Info</option>
<option value="2">Resr</option>
<option value="3">Pro</option>
<option value="4">Geo</option>
<option value="5">Site's</option>
<option value="6">Well</option>
<option value="7">Link</option>
<option value="#" selected="selected">Please select</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="name">Name:</label></td><td><input name="name" type="text" size="40" maxlength="40" id="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Update"> <input type="reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The problem is that the name field now contains all the names from the option dropdown list and not only the one i selected.

Comment: have some html to back that up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [:selected Selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) to get selected `option`, and then `.text()` to get its name.

```
var name = $('#categories option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 2):

try this....

```
$(document).ready(
function()
{
    //check for change on the categories menu
    $('#categories').change(function() { 

    //get category value
    name = $("#categories option:selected").text();
    $('#name').val(name)

    });
});
```

Hope its help

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to use `$("#categories").val()` instead of `.text()`.

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/wZAM7/

Comment: That's what I originally thought - but the select option can have a different value to the text displayed. For instance, a country select might have the name as the text but the ISO code as the value.

Answer (score -1):

Read jQuery Docs and shown Examples in the [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) function.